# SVG images are not displayed in gmail

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, svg, browser

I am sending an email with an svg logo in it .Png works fine.but I am unable to load SVG .I checked in firefox and chrome and none of them works.I am using laravel framework. Is this an issue with framework or browser. The chrome error is The requested URL /proxyxxx  was not found on this server.

Comment: Could you copy the code here ?

Comment: <center><a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank"><img height="28px" src="https://cdn.example.com/logo.png" width="126px"></a></center>

Comment: SVG is not supported by gmail. It is however working in Apple Mail, for example.
Mails are beasts - you have to assume 1995 www capabilities and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 31):

SVG images are not supported by Gmail and many other clients.

You can check which clients support SVG images here https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-on-svg-support-in-email/

Comment: 4 years later, and this is still true..

Comment: @Dika it's still here in 2023...

Comment: @Mahdi still here in 2024...

Comment: @Mahdi still here in 2024...